# Azure Database for PostgreSQL server is displaying 100% CPU utilization

Tags: postgresql, azure, cpu-usage, azure-database-postgresql

Azure Database for the PostgreSQL server is displaying 100% CPU utilization every day from 10 AM to 12 PM. The load on the server is minimal when this is happening. Did anyone face the same issue? What could be the probable cause for this to happen?

Attached a screenshot of the CPU usage for 3 days (below are the observations).

- The peak is reached between 10 AM to 12 PM every day.
- There is a sharp increase (If the increase was due to the load then the peak should be attained gradually)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your long running queries to understand what is causing high processing time and update your database tables Statistics regularly by using the “Analyze” command.

If you maxed out CPU, scaling up your server by increasing the number of vCores is a good approach to enlarge your resources to be able to accommodate your workload.

Enable Azure PostgreSQL Query Store to be able to view your long running queries:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-query-store

Also please follow this quick tips for PostgreSQL

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Database-Support-Blog/Azure-Database-for-PostgreSQL-performance-Quick-Tips/ba-p/369125